# Wouldn’t Type.CreateInstance made more sense than Activator.CreateInstance?

Tags: c#

1) If we want to create an instance of a given type during runtime ( thus using late binding ), then we need to call Activator.CreateInstance. But wouldn’t it be more efficient if Type class had such a method?  If nothing else, Type.CreateInstance  could return strongly typed instance instead of System.Object?!

2) Type.GetType enables us to pass into it only the friendly name of the assembly containing the type, thus it doesn’t enable us to specify the absolute path to this  assembly.

Any idea why Type.GetType allowing us to specify an absolute path to the assembly would be a bad idea?

thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You can, but I'm not sure if these are nicer then using Activator.CreateInstance

```
object obj = someType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes).Invoke(null);
object obj = someType.InvokeMember("", BindingFlags.CreateInstance, null, null, null);
```

2) Not using a full Assembly Qualified Name to load a possible unexpected type and can have strange results as explained [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/suzcook/archive/2003/05/30/57159.aspx).

Specifying the location to load the assembly from is something only Assembly.LoadFrom does. Assembly.LoadFrom is deprecated in the newer .Net version. The reason for that is when you use LoadFrom you do need to be aware that the assembly is loaded in a different context and [unexpected](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/FusionLoaderContextsUnableToCastObjectOfTypeWhateverToTypeWhatever.aspx) things could happen. So it is a good thing Type.GetType does not has such a feature.

Comment: “I'm not sure what you mean by absolute path, because loading an assembly from a specified location is someting only Assembly.LoadFrom does.” By absolute path I meant something like C:\SomeApp\Assembly.dll

Comment: So the answer is: That would be a bad idea, because those assemblies are loaded in a different context. See http://www.hanselman.com/blog/FusionLoaderContextsUnableToCastObjectOfTypeWhateverToTypeWhatever.aspx

Comment: urgh, I skipped the part of the book where it talks about context, thinking I don't have to know about it.

Answer (score 3):

`Type` has a single purpose: it defines a unique "Type" within the runtime environment.

Keeping `Activator` a separate type, as well as `Assembly` for the assembly information, is a good thing.  Having small classes which define a single purpose and usage is a better design.

Moving `Activator.CreateInstance` into `Type` would not make it more efficient - it *might* make it easier to conceptualize *in your specific scenario*, but it would cause type to become larger and more complex.  I personally find the current design very clean and nice, and am glad that they've kept the Type class unique to defining a type, and left other information (such as Assembly info and construction) in separate types.

Answer (score 2):

As for your question as to why Type.GetType doesn't let you specify the full path to the assembly, again we go back to the single responsibility principle. Assembly.Load is how you load assemblies, Type.GetType only works with currently-loaded assemblies.

Answer (score 1):

1. Activating a type may need to work with COM interop and Remoting, so having Type deal with that is putting too many eggs in one basket (aka poor design). You do have Activator.CreateInstance<T>(), but you need to know the type at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

Using Reflection, you may also search for the right ConstructorInfo and invoke it for your type, then you will get a strongly-typed instance and be able to late-bind it.

**EDIT**
ConstructorInfo.Invoke(object[])
It is not stronly-typed and one will be obliged to type-cast before using the new instance of Type T.

Comment: Using ConstructorInfo still doesn't give you strong typing: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ycw1y17(v=VS.90).aspx  A cast is necessary any time you use reflection.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can, just need to make an extra hop.  You can use Type.GetConstructor() and call the returned ConstructorInfo.Invoke() method.

Type.GetType() will also take a assembly-qualified name.  Or you could use Assembly.Load() and Assembly.GetType() to get the Type instance.

Comment: "Type.GetType() will also take a assembly-qualified name." I realize that.But why can't Type.GetType also allow us to specify the path to the assembly?

Comment: Because it is *very* rare that an assembly is ever loaded from an absolute path.  If you have to then you can, an extra hop through Assembly.LoadFile().  Avoid this at all cost.